# How to horizontally center TopTabNavigator in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I've been struggling to apply the proper styling so that my Top Tab Navigator is horizontally centered on the screen. I've tried applying AlignItems: center to the different style props but that does not seem to work. Any tips?

Here is the documentation I have been following: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs";
import Creators from "../../screens/Creators/Creators";
import Feed from "../../screens/Feed/Feed";
import Profile from "../../screens/Profile/Profile";

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function TabNav() {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            tabBarOptions={{
                labelStyle: {
                    fontSize: 12,
                    color: "white",
                },
                tabStyle: {
                    width: 100,
                    height: 40,
                    marginTop: 50,
                },
                indicatorStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: "white",
                },
                style: {
                    backgroundColor: "#03182d",
                },
            }}
        >
            <Tab.Screen name="Creators" component={Creators} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}

export default TabNav;
```

Comment: remove tabStyle and it will work perfectly or remove only width.

Comment: Thank you this solution worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove tabStyle and it will work perfectly like this

```
 <Tab.Navigator
            tabBarOptions={{
                labelStyle: {
                    fontSize: 12,
                    color: "white",
                },
                //remove this
                //tabStyle: {
                //    width: 100,
                //    height: 40,
                //    marginTop: 50,
                },
                indicatorStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: "white",
                },
                style: {
                    backgroundColor: "#03182d",
                },
            }}
        >
            <Tab.Screen name="Creators" component={Creators} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
```

or remove only width as it is smudging your tabs